# LongListSelector, pull when few items (pull to refresh issue)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have a pull to refresh solution for `LongListSelector` in wp8.

When there are only a few items so that all can be contained without scrolling, I don't get any scroll movement when pulling on the `LongListSelector`. This causes problems with pull to refresh.

How can I get the `LongListSelector` behave like a list in a scrollviewer, ie it scrolls when being pulled regardless of the number of items?

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: I don't remember actually...